# Spring Data and QueryDSL query returns wrong type (com.querydsl.core.support.QueryBase<>)

Tags: java, spring, querydsl

I am working on my first Spring project using postgreSQL and JPA and I like it, but now I am stuck.
I used the findBy... methods from Spring and now I want also use QueryDSL for dynamic query with optional parameters..

So I added the dependencys:

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>com.querydsl</groupId>
        <artifactId>querydsl-jpa</artifactId>
        <version>4.1.1</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.querydsl</groupId>
        <artifactId>querydsl-apt</artifactId>
        <version>4.1.1</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
        <version>1.7.7</version>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
```

and the plugin

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>com.mysema.maven</groupId>
    <artifactId>apt-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>1.1.3</version>
    <executions>
      <execution>
        <goals>
          <goal>process</goal>
        </goals>
        <configuration>
          <outputDirectory>target/generated-sources/java</outputDirectory>
          <processor>com.querydsl.apt.jpa.JPAAnnotationProcessor</processor>
        </configuration>
      </execution>
    </executions>
  </plugin>
```

Ok, I have a Domain, Person Class:

```
@Entity
public class Person implements Serializable {
@Id
private Long personId;
private String firstname;
private String lastname;
private Date birthdate;
```

..

and a Repository:

```
public interface PersonRepository extends JpaRepository<Person, Long> {
    List<Person> findByLastnameAndFirstnameAllIgnoreCase(String lastname, String firstname);
    List<Person> findByBirthdate(Date birthdate);
}
```

and the Servie..

```
public interface PersonService {
    public Person save(Person person);
    public Person findOne(Long personId);
    public List<Person> findAll();
    public List<Person> findByLastnameAndFirstnameAllIgnoreCase(String lastname, String firstname);
    List<Person> findByBirthdate(Date birthdate);
}
```

And the PersonServiseImpl..

So, if I am right I can make a new Class in the Person Domain Package for example

```
public class findPatients() {

@PersistenceContext
EntityManager em;

QPerson person = QPerson.person;
JPAQuery query = new JPAQuery(em);

Person bob = query.from(person).where(person.firstname.eq("Bob")); 
}
```

If I do this, I get an "Incompatible types" Error, requiering: domain.Person found: com.querydsl.core.support.QueryBase<>

Comment: Instead of trying to work around Spring Data JPA use it. See [this section] of the reference guide.

Comment: your link don´t work

Comment: http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/1.10.1.RELEASE/reference/html/#core.extensions.querydsl

Comment: Ok, I tryed this but it gave me an error, if I extend JPArepository an, QueryDslPredicateExecutor, I cannot use the findOne method from the jparepository, but I use that in some cases in my project. Can you give me an example how I have to use this please.

Comment: That would be weird, using the same setup here without problems. Show your repository (add it to your question).

Comment: I added the full repository and the service

Comment: There is no `QueryDslPredicateExecutor` in the extends clause?!

Comment: The Problem is, when I put it there and run a Maven clean -> Maven install, it will get the error: [ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:compile (default-compile) on project project-core: Compilation failure: Compilation failure:
[ERROR] theClass.java:[101,42] cannot access com.mysema.query.types.Predicate
[ERROR] class file for com.mysema.query.types.Predicate not found

Comment: I guess that has to do with the supported QueryDSL version. Which Spring Data JPA version are you using?

Comment: I user 1.9.2.RELEASE

Comment: Please don't add code, xml, snippets as comments, please improve your question with it. That version supports querydsl 3 not 4. Use the 1.10 version to have querydsl 4 support.

Comment: Ok, first that was the problem I never checked the version.. and on Sprin.io is the hint that querydsl is supported in the new version... a BIG thanks to you ;)

Comment: maybe you can help me also in this case http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37425016/spring-data-and-querydsl-how-to-find-by-multiple-criteria-in-one-row-and-a-onet